# SQL Transaction Times Out

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, transactions

When I execute the following SQL in the management studio the query returns the expected result:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table WHERE field = value;
```

However when my client application (WinForms) execute's this SQL in the middle of a Transaction the query Times Out without returning a value.  I suspect this is because the Transaction includes other SQL statements which are adding to / amending the same 'table'.

How do I work around this?

Comment: Looks like a deadlock. Are there any other activity related to the same table?

Comment: A deadlock will not time out but will result in a deadlock error. A time out can however be caused by an earlier blocking lock.

Comment: Do you have access to the activity monitor on the server / database? You would be able to see where your conflict is.

Comment: What transaction isolation level are you using?

Comment: What are you attempting to do?  If this is for primary key uses, it's not going to work like you expect...

Comment: can you end the 'other SQL statements' transaction and start a new transaction with the MAX call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"SELECT MAX(ID)" is an aggregate function and will do a lot of locking on the table - a shared read lock can potentially be taken on all the records in the table, certainly on all those that match your criteria, and others depending on whether row or page locks are used. If there is an outstanding write lock on *any* of these records that the MAX wants to lock, then the MAX will time out. You need to understand what other locks are in place at the same time. If you are using SQL Server, then you can use SQL Profiler to get a trace which will show you all the locks on that table, including locks from other transactions.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I simply moved the SQL statement using the MAX function before the transaction started, and stored the value as a variable for later use inside the transation.