# Does the first insert into a table effectively lock the entire table?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, locking, transactionscope

**Scenario:** 
TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress) query embedded within a wrapper TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required). Prior to the "Suppress" query there is another query associated with the wrapper "Required" TransactionScope.

These two queries only overlap on one table. The prior "Required" query Inserts into the table and the latter "Suppress" query Selects from the table. Ignore how stupid this is and the fact that the "Suppress" query will only read the unlocked rows and therefore will not include the newly inserted results.

**Behavior:** 
The behavior I'm seeing is that if there are rows within the table the Insert will succeed and then the Select will read the unlocked rows and then move on. However, if the table is empty the Insert will succeed, but then the Select will get stuck as being blocked by the Insert.

**Question:** 
What I'm trying to get is a conceptual understanding of how the locking is being tracked in this scenario. I used to think of table locking as being a kind of bit toggle where the table was either locked or unlocked, but it seems that it is more like a CASE statement with a NOT EXISTS; in the absence of an unlocked row the table is locked as opposed to the table is unlocked, but every row in it is currently in a locked state.

Everything that I've been able to find indicates that there are indeed different levels of locking (table, row, page, etc), but I can't find anything that states in explicit terms that if a table is empty and row locks exist on data being inserted then a table lock is implied. Originally I would've expected the Select to simply return a Null, but since this isn't the behavior I figured I'd reach out to the experts and see if someone can give me a definitive understanding.

**Notes:** 
RDBMS: SQL Server 2012 
.NET Framework: 4.0 
Core Behavior: If a record exists in the table prior to the Insert then both queries succeed, but if the table is empty prior to the Insert then the Select gets blocked by the Insert.

Table:

```
Create Table Random(ID Int Identity, Word Varchar(50), TimeInserted DateTime)
```

Insert Query:

```
Insert Random(Word, TimeInserted)
Select 'Word', GetDate()
```

Select Query:

```
Select Max(TimeInserted)
From Random
Where Word Like 'A%'
```

Comment: Are you using serializable isolation for the select? Also what is the table structure and queries?

Comment: Yes serializable, the table structure and queries shouldn't matter. The "Required" query is an INSERT that precludes the "Suppress" query that is a SELECT. Consider the table to be three columns, an IDENTITY column, a Varchar(50) and a DateTime column. The insert adds the Varchar(50) and DateTime (Identity autoincrements) and the select is reading the DateTime.

Comment: The queries and table structures definitely do matter because this determines whether it just locks the entire object or a key range and what specific range is locked if the latter.

Comment: Okey doke, question updated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Those queries should always block irrespective of whether the table is empty or not except at read uncommitted or snapshot isolation (or if you use the `with (readpast)` hint). The insert will be adding a row with the `MAX(TimeInserted)` and the `SELECT` query won't be able to read it until the insert is committed.

Comment: That's what makes sense... I suppose I must be missing something.

Comment: Actually, there is one other component to the Select. Updating info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default IsolationLevel of TransactionScope is "Serializable".  According to [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), in this isolation level "Volatile data can be read but not modified, and no new data can be added during the transaction".  "Serializable" is very deadlock-prone.

The default IsolationLevel of an SQLTransaction is ReadCommitted.  Try declaring your transaction scope like this

```
using (var scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout}))
```

It may solve your problem.

More on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The highest isolation level, Serializable, provides a high degree of protection against interruptive transactions, **but requires that each transaction complete before any other transactions are allowed to operate on the data**.

Comment: Thanks for the information, it's interesting, but I'm actually not looking for a solution to the locking I'm just trying to understand the behavior I'm observing. Why would the read succeed when records exist, but lock when no records exist?

Comment: Does the "Suppress" query is always reading the "not commited" inserted reccord?

Comment: I am using serializable, but I'm only adding data in one transaction. The select is only reading the data which is allowed. As you stated, the volatile data can be read, but not modified; I'm not modifying.

Comment: It reads the records that already existed in the table, it does not read the "not committed" records.

Comment: The problem may come from the "MAX" function.  It may try to lock the "not commited" Inserted reccord.heck this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401861/sql-transaction-times-out)

Comment: But then why does it work when records exist in the table already? The max value is definitely going to be in the "not committed" records because they contain GetDate() and are within a Serialized transaction.

Comment: Does the Select Max(TimeInserted) return the time of the "not committed" record?  Im trying to figure out like you what could happen and im starting to run out of answers.

Comment: No, it returns the Max value of the record that existed in the table prior to the insert; the "not committed" records are not seen. The question at hand is why the table appears to lock when the table is empty prior to the insert, but does not when records exist prior to the insert. I can rationalize an answer for why this is the case as I described in the CASE NOT EXISTS logic in my post, but I can't find any definitive resource that explains this behavior.

Comment: Trying different isolation levels may help you figure out all of this but I can't figure anything more.  Logically the "MAX" function should have return NULL (at least).